# CSS: right-align with relative positioning

Tags: css

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>
<p class="inline-block">hello world</p>
</div>
```

I'd like to use relative positioning (not float or absolute...the element needs to remain in the normal flow here) to place some text in a P element against the right edge of its parent element. The goal is to have the list items on the left-hand side and the text in the p element on the right. Surely there has to be an easy way. Any suggestions?

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pnkM/).

Comment: What's wrong with float?

Comment: Content is taken out of the normal flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with relative positioning. While floats will be taken out of normal flow, they can be cleared, as if to keep them in the flow. http://jsfiddle.net/MPLwv/

```
ul {
    float: left;
}
p {
    float: right;
}
div:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both; /*Cleared!*/
}
```